# Hibernate HQL query join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to access data from my accounts table, I have 3 tables, User, AccountAccess and Accounts I am trying to return a row/s from Accounts based on user login.
here is the schema:

[image]

here is the sql that does return the correct data:

```
Select a.COMPANY_NAME, a.NAME, u.LOGIN  from T_ACCOUNTS a, T_ACCOUNTACCESS  acc, T_USER u where a.id = acc.accounts_id and acc.USER_LOGIN  = u.LOGIN and u.LOGIN = 'gman'
```

now here is my attempted at HQL:

```
@Query("Select a from Accounts a INNER JOIN AccountAccess ac ON a.id = ac.account JOIN User u ON acc.user = u.login WHERE u.login = 'gman'")
List<Accounts> findAccountId();
```

Go easy on me, only start learning this HQL today and have spent a while on this, your help is appreciated.

Gman

Comment: Can you verify if this works - "select account from Accounts acc, AccountAccess access, User user where acc.id = access.accountId and access.userLogin = user.login and user.login = 'gman'" Replace the variables based on your object model.

Comment: Also can you post your hibernate object mapping code?